# Reactive jdbc driver support for Oracle database

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, reactive-programming

Is there any reactive jdbc driver support for Oracle database compatible with spring boot 2 version? I want to use it in production environment.

Answer (score 3):

The upcoming DB 20c release of the Oracle JDBC drivers has the built-in extensions.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on Reactive extensions for the Oracle JDBC driver that uses java.util.concurrent.Flow and Reactive streams. However, this is available in our next release.

Comment: Thank you Nirmala for the update. Could you please tell the library name and version?

Answer (score 0):

The Reactive extensions to the Oracle JDBC driver will work with all Reactive Streams libraries including Reactor, RxJava, Akka Streams and others.

Comment: Which version of oracle JDBC driver has this support?